# Laravel active menu class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have been searching for a solution to add a active class to a menu but cannot figure it out. I have checked all over the web but nothing seems to work. I am working with Laravel 5.8

In my web.php I have:

```
Route::get('categories/{title}-{id}/products', 'CategoryProductController@showProducts')->name('categories.products.show');
```

Then in my show.blade.php

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
     <a href="{{route('categories.products.show', ['title' => $category->title, 'id' => $category->identifier])}}" class="list-group-item">
     {{$category->title}}
     </a>
@endforeach
```

What I have tried is:

```
<a href="{{route('categories.products.show', ['title' => $category->title, 'id' => $category->identifier])}}" class="{{ (request()->is('categories.products.show')) ? 'active' : '' }} list-group-item">
{{$category->title}}
</a>
```

and

```
<a href="{{route('categories.products.show', ['title' => $category->title, 'id' => $category->identifier])}}" class="{{ request()->routeIs('categories.products.show', ['title' => $category->title, 'id' => $category->identifier]) ? 'active' : '' }} list-group-item">
{{$category->title}}
</a>
```

I have tried a couple of other solutions as well but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Tried it with `Route::currentRouteName()` and then they all become active.

Comment: Ok, got it now, didn't quite read the question. You want to check the `$category->identifier` I guess. See if `request()->route('id')` gives you the currently set `{id}` route parameter and check accordingly

Comment: Hmmm I did `{{ (request()->route('id')) ? 'active' : '' }}` and stil all of the links become active.

Comment: Echo out `request()->route('id')` in your blade and see what it contains. Use `{{ ($category->identifier == request()->route('id')) ? 'active' : '' }}` as I said earlier

Comment: Yes, Thank you! `{{ ($category->identifier == request()->route('id')) ? 'active' : '' }}` did the trick. I was not getting the part for `$category->identifier ==`